# How to mock observable and geter from injected mocked service

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm new to testing and I'm already lost.

I have a service, which I want to test:

**animation.service.ts**

```
... 
public constructor(private animationStateService: AnimationStateService,
                   frameStateService: FrameStateService) {

     frameStateService.changedAvailableFrames
            .pipe(
                ...
                // Some code in pipe
                ...
            )
            ).subscribe(() => {
                ...
                // Some code in subscribe
                ...
            }
        ) }

public start(): void {

    if (this.animationStateService.status !== AnimationStatus.Stopped) {
        return;
    }

    this.animationStateService.changeStatus(AnimationStatus.Preloading);
    this.preloaderService.preloadAllFrames()
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                this.run();
            }
        ); 
}
...
```

The injected services:

**frame-state.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class FrameStateService {

private changedAvailableFramesSubject: Subject<LayerId> = new Subject();
public changedAvailableFrames: Observable<LayerId> = this.changedAvailableFramesSubject.asObservable();

public constructor() {}
...
```

**animation-state.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AnimationStateService {

public get status(): AnimationStatus { return this.state.animation.status; }
...
```

In my tests I want to mock the `changedAvailableFrames` from `FrameStateService` and also the `status` from `AnimationStateService`.

What I already did:

**animation.service.spec.ts**

```
describe("AnimationService", () => {

    let animationService: SpyObj<AnimationService>;
    let animationStateService: SpyObj<AnimationStateService>;
    let frameStateService: SpyObj<FrameStateService>;

    beforeEach(() => {

        const spyFrameStateService = createSpyObj("FrameStateService", [""]);
        const spyAnimationStateService = createSpyObj("AnimationStateService", ["changeStatus", "status"]);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            AnimationService,
            {provide: FrameService, useValue: spyFrameService},
            {provide: AnimationStateService, useValue: spyAnimationStateService},
            ]
        });

        animationService = TestBed.get(AnimationService);
        animationStateService = TestBed.get(AnimationStateService);
        frameStateService = TestBed.get(FrameStateService);

        frameStateService.changedAvailableFrames.and.returnValue(of());

    });

    it("Should call changeStatus", () => {

        // Arrange
        animationStateService.status.and.returnValue(AnimationStatus.Stopped);

        // Act
        animationService.start();

        // Assert
        expect(animationStateService.changeStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

})
```

The errors what I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

At this point I'm totally lost and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const spyFrameStateService = createSpyObj("FrameStateService", [""]);`

Will create a mock object with no methods and no properties (the second argument should go away for this case. If you want mock with method `hello` you make it like `createSpyObj("FrameStateService", ["hello"]);`). Unfortunately using `createSpyObj` you cannot create properties.

But you need there property `changedAvailableFramesSubject`, right? Because its subscribed by your tested service.

So instead of mocking using `createSpyObj` create a simple object:

```
{provide: FrameStateService, useValue: { changedAvailableFramesSubject: new Subject() },
```

And make it emit anytime you want:

```
const frameStateService = TestBed.get(FrameStateService);
frameStateService.changedAvailableFramesSubject.next('your emitted value');
```

Comment: I need `changedAvailableFrames` `Observable` from `FrameStateService`, not `Subject` and not from `FrameService`.

Comment: @Gabriel now I see ... you had `FrameService` in your test so that confused me. Should be `FrameStateService`. Updated code.

Comment: By the way, it is easy to create properties on a spy object.  The spy object is no different than any other JavaScript object, you just create a property on it by defining it such as `spyFrameStateService.newProperty = 'foo'`

Comment: @dmcgrandle You would have to do it before creating test module because `changedAvailableFramesSubject` must be there on the service instantiation. Problematic line:`public changedAvailableFrames: Observable<LayerId> = this.changedAvailableFramesSubject.asObservable();`

Comment: @MartinNuc Sure, it could be done immediately after declaration of the spyObj. I was just pointing out that in the general case it is simple to add a property to a spy object.